# C++ virtual destructor and symbol referencing error

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

Only because I want to have virtual methods to apply polymorphism in my parent and child class, I put in virtual destructor. I do however, keep getting error

> Child:: ~Child()
>
> Child:: Child() as symbol referencing error.

```
class Parent {
public: Parent();
        virtual ~Parent();
};

class Child {
public:
      Child();   
       ~Child();
};
```

Comment: Did you intend for `Child` to inherit from `Parent`? I wasn't sure, so I left that part alone, but the names hint that you might...

Comment: This is not valid C++ syntax. This is not a real question. Tell us what you are trying to do, show us real code and exact errors you are getting. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I edited the c++ - should be good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the destructor, not just declare it.

```
virtual ~Parent() {};
```

Comment: No, no, I did that in my code also. did implement for both parent and child.

Comment: Yes yes - that is what you need :-) the linker needs to be able to find it

Comment: oh, ahh, I was able to link and compile, but the error came from the file that I was using that Object. :(

Comment: Stupid mistake in the Makefile, forgot to add in line for .o file, oops, but great to learn about virtual destructor. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to put the `;` here? (I know it's allowed, but still...)

Comment: @curiousguy A valid point. Usually I do not - but I must admit even after 20 years my style varies. I made a quick edit to cut&paste so I left it. If I remember I remove it. No excuses though - normally I would have removed it if I remembered ;-)